# Rotation between two Frames

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames, tensor-calculus, inertial-frames, linear-algebra

I have a simple three dimensional frame which I use to define a certain tensor $A$. I want to define a second frame which corresponds to a rotation of the first one define by the Euler angles ($\alpha,\beta,\gamma$). What is the exact operation I should use to change the basis of the tensor, do I simply multiply said Tensor by the Euler matrix, i.e.

$B=EulerMatrix\,A$,

or do I need to carry the change of basis as:

$B=T\,A\,T^{-1}$,

where $T$ is the matrix that would define said transformation? I may be mixing some concepts here or there may be an easier to do this, so If you have any suggestions I would also appreciate it.

My thanks in advance

Comment: The latter is what you should do.

Comment: I stumbled upon the Wigner matrices while searching for more information, would they be easier to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact answer depends on your conventions for defining your Euler matrix, 
but whatever your conventions, you can work it out like this:

Let $V$ be a vector and suppose it is rotated into $V' = E \, V$ by your Euler matrix.

You know that the expression $V^T A \, V$ is a scalar, so it must be the same in both frames:

${V'}^T B \,V' =  V^T A \, V$.

i.e.,

$(EV)^T B \, E \, V = V^T A \, V$

i.e.,

$ V^TE^T B \, E \, V = V^T A \, V$

so

$E^T B \, E = A$

or

$B = E \,A \, E^T$

(using $E^T = E^{-1}$ because $E$ is a rotation matrix.)

If you use a different convention for rotations, for example $V' = E^T \, V$ or $V' = VE$, the calculation still goes through, with simple modifications.

Comment: E will always be the Euler rotation matrix then? Additionally, would there be an easier way of doing this, for instance with the wigner matrices?

Comment: E will always be the Euler rotation matrix, but there are different conventions for it: one person's E may be another person's E^T.  And there are two conventions for transforming a vector with E: left multiplication by a row vector, or right-multiplication by a column vector. You just have to know your conventions and use them consistently.

Comment: My memory of Wigner matrices is sketchy, but I think they are for a different kind of problem, namely rotating operators that have good angular momentum quantum numbers (J,Jz).
For rotating regular vectors, you want the Euler matix.
You could look into quaternions, but in my opinion they are harder to use, not easier.

Answer (score 0):

The congruent transformation ${\rm B} = T {\rm A} T^{-1}$ is what you want.

Essentially reading it from right to left you are doing to following

1. Transform from the world coordinates to the local coordinates with $T^{-1}$
2. Apply the local tensor ${\rm A}$
3. Transform back from local coordinates to world coordinates with $T$

Comment: And what will T be?

Comment: Same as _OP_ $T$. The transformation matrix.